# Is there a way to build visual plugins in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, electron, vscode-extensions

I would like to build a plugin where I put a Chart or a Tree component for people to drag and drop and use/build their own flows. Is this possible to build in VS Code? Are there any examples or documents on how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's possible. You can use a WebView instance to show graphical output (written in HTML). In my vscode extension (https://github.com/mike-lischke/vscode-antlr4) I display a visual parse tree using D3.js:

[image]

In the graphic you can collapse nodes, zoom in/out, move the viewport with the mouse and more.